# Putting \, to a string in R

Tags: r

It seems that I cannot put sequence '\,' to a string in R. For example, I tried to use gsub() to replace certain substring with '\,' but so far I can put only ',', eg. (all examples run in RStudio console):

```
gsub('x', '\\,', 'yxz')
[1] "y,z"

gsub('x', '\,', 'xyz')
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\,"

gsub('x', '\\\,', 'yxz')
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\\\,"
```

Similarly, I tried to use '\,' as a separator in numbers (yes, for TeX):

```
format(1000000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark='\\,')
[1] "1,000,000"

format(1000000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark='\,')
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\,"

format(1000000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark='\\\,')
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\\\,"

format(1000000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark='<xyz>')
[1] "1<xyz>000<xyz>000"
```

Would you know how to put '\,' correctly to a string? I am probably missing something around escaping of backslash sequences in R.

Comment: Add one more `\ ` in there? `cat(gsub('x', '\\\\,', 'yxz'))`

Comment: @RonakShah, did you use `cat` to see that `\\ ` is actually a single character?

Comment: The problem appears to be that the pattern argument of regex functions like `gsub` shares an escape character (`\`) with the standard escape character of R. So doubling of the escape character is needed for "pattern" arguments (but not "replace" arguments).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are after correctly, you can add one more `\` to the replacement. It will *display* as `\\`, but if you `cat` it or count how many characters that is, you would see it is just 1.

```
demo <- gsub('x', '\\\\,', 'yxz')
demo
# [1] "y\\,z"
cat(demo)
# y\,z
nchar(demo)
# [1] 4
out <- format(1000000, scientific=FALSE, big.mark='\\\\,')
out
# [1] "1\\,000\\,000"
cat(out)
# 1\,000\,000
nchar(out)
# [1] 11
```